# Showing coin weight using balanced scale

Tags: combinatorics

There are $10$ coins, one with weight $1,2,\ldots,10$ each, but they all look the same. Joe wants to demonstrate that he knows the weight of at least one coin by using a balanced scale. What is the minimum number of weighings that he needs?

Using five weighings is possible if he wants to show the coin $10$: he weighs it against $\{1,9\},\{2,8\},\{3,7\},\{4,6\}$, and $\{5\}$. The results will uniquely identify the coin with weight $10$.

Comment: Your fifth weighing is irrelevant. (OK, I see, it is not, but that gave me an idea  ...)

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I think it's relevant; otherwise it could be the coin $9$ weighed against $\{1,8\},\{2,7\},\{3,6\}$, and $\{4,5\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One coin can be demonstrated to be $10$ in one weighing:
$$1+2+3+4=10.$$

Comment: That's very clever!